# Which scripture are these verses from?

Tags: identification-request

You are supposed to say this mantra (sloka?) after performing any ritual to atone for any errors made:

> yasya smṛtyā ca nāmoktayā tapojñayākriyādiṣu
>   nyūnaṃ saṃpūrṇatāṃ yāti sadhyo vande tamacyutam
>
> यस्य स्मृत्या च नामोक्तया तपोज्ञयाक्रियादिषु
>   न्यूनं संपूर्णतां याति सध्यो वन्दे तमच्युतम्
>
> I praise that Eternal Lord by remembering whom and uttering whose name all deficiences are supplied in every sacrifice and ceremony.

This mantra is cited in the commentary on the *Yajnvalkya Smriti* called the *Mitākṣarā* [here](https://archive.org/details/yajnavalkyasmrit00yj/page/42).

Which scripture is this mantra from?

Comment: what is your source? book?? It seems like you know these mantras, may be scripture as well?

Comment: You should add questions in text. Images are not substitutes for texts. You can use OCR to convert image to text.

Comment: @CR241 From here: https://archive.org/details/yajnavalkyasmrit00yj/page/42

Comment: So, what topic is this Q about? Identification request?

Comment: @Rickross It is about identifying source of a shloka. So, Identification request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a mantra. This is a shloka from Narada Purana Part 1 (poorvartha) Chapter 17 shloka 108. This is spoken by sage Narada while explaining the Dvadashi vrata.